# how to remove button in Uitableview when table is int edit mode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I creating the one UITable view with the 2 sections in with when i load the data into the uitablew it's working fine,

But my problem is how to resolve one sorting button is disable in section 0 and row 0

which more discribe into the following image.

[image]

please help to solve my problem

in advance thanking to your valuable time spend on my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy.

Listen on the UITableViewDataSource call [`tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW30)

Like this:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    return NO;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

If you don't not where to place the method, place it next to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

Set `showsReorderControl` to NO property of cell

```
cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
```

In addition, if the data source implements `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` to return NO, the reordering control does not appear in that designated row. You need to check indexPath and return NO for it.